# Why am I getting the error 'NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<List<int>>' has no instance getter 'shape'.'

Tags: list, dart

I am trying to create a function that utilizes the shape method for lists in dart. My problem is that I cannot call shape on a 2d list that is passed into the function. The strange thing is that shape works fine on a list that was created within the function. I do not understand why that is because they appear to be equal in all ways. Here is my code:

```dart
void main() {
  List<List<int>> image = [
    [0, 10, 10, 0],
    [20, 30, 30, 20],
    [10, 20, 20, 10],
    [0, 5, 5, 0]
  ];

  testFunc(image);
}

void testFunc(image) {
  List<List<int>> list = [
    [0, 10, 10, 0],
    [20, 30, 30, 20],
    [10, 20, 20, 10],
    [0, 5, 5, 0]
  ];

  // works. output: 4
  print(list.shape[0]);

  // does not work. output: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<List<int>>' has no instance getter 'shape'.
  print(image.shape[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the `shape` function is a static extension method on the type `List<List<int>>`, or some supertype of that.

The static type of the `image` parameter here is `dynamic`.
Extension methods are applied based on the static type of the receiver expression, and `dynamic` is not a subtype of `List<List<int>>` so the `shape` methods does not apply.
(The `dynamic` type is special in that *no* extension methods apply to it, because it's considered as having all members itself.)

If you change the code to

```dart
void testFunc(List<List<int>> image) { 
 // ...
}
```

then it will likely start working.